# how to open html page using trigger

Tags: php

i am using database trigger

when database row updated i want to get real time notification like change happened now

suppose i am using message table in my database

suppose user inserted value in message table. i want change should be noted using

trigger at real time and then i want open an html page when row inserted in my

message table then html page should open or an alert box show notification

that"you received a new message".

Please help me to solve this problem
 for example
    CREATE TRIGGER notifyMe

```
ON table1

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 

  AS
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'DB AutoMailer',

    @recipients = 'user@example.com',

    @body = 'The DB has changed',

    @subject = 'DB Change';

 in above example mail is sending but i want to open html page i need syntax   to open html page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well below is a example of what you need exactly:

***javascript***

```
    var old_count = 0;

setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "file.php",
        success : function(data){
            if (data > old_count) {
                alert('new record on i_case');
                old_count = data;
            }
        }
    });
},1000);
```

***then php***

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM i_case";
$qry = pg_query($connection, $sql);
$row = pg_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row['count'];
```